# How to Combine text in excel column using Textjoin

Tags: excel, textjoin

Sorry My english So bad.
I want to combine data in 2 row.

```
=TEXTJOIN("",true,G4:G12,"")
```

***Image***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `TEXTJOIN()` like-

```
=TEXTJOIN("*",TRUE,B2&$C$2:$C$4)
```

[image]